# Is it possible to subscribe users to Office 365 groups

Tags: office365api, azure-ad-graph-api

We are automating the creation of Office 365 groups and adding users. Is it possible to subscribe the users as well. I can see that there is a subscribeByMail method on groups
http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_subscribebymail
but this is for the current user only. Is there a way for a service application to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Based on my investigation, the group mail subscribe only support for the sign-in user. This API is a beta version, you may not use it in the product and if you have any feedback about it, you can try to submit from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).